# How to make RadioListTile widget disabled in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I'm using the `RadioListTile` widget in my application and I want to disable changing the value after some condition is satisfied. and there is no `isButtonDisabled` prop just like in `Radio` widget. how can I disable this widget(stop the value from changing)?

By the time I was writing the above statement I figured it out and it was easy.
so Ill post the question and will answer it below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  bool evaluate = false;
  int value;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        RadioListTile<int>(
          value: 0,
          isThreeLine: false,
          title: Text(
            'radio 1',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          groupValue: value,
          onChanged: (value) => evaluate ? null : value = 0,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        RadioListTile<int>(
          value: 1,
          isThreeLine: false,
          title: Text(
            'radio 2',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          groupValue: value,
          onChanged: (value) => evaluate ? null : value = 1,
          activeColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        InkWell(
          onTap: () {
            evaluate = true;
          },
          child: Container(
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Submit answer',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whenever `onChange` is null the component will become disabled. You should be able to do something link this instead:

```dart
onChanged: evaluate ? null : (value) => value = 0,
```

I would also rename `evaluate` to make it easier to understand, something like `alreadyProvided`, `notAllowed`, `disabled` or whatever makes sense, the most important thing is to really represent why it can't be changed.

In the end it could look like:

```dart
onChanged: alreadyProvided ? null : (value) => value = 0,
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you have already figured out the answer from the code.
the solution is to declare bool value `evaluate` in my case then on button click make that value true and setstate with that value and on the `onChanged` prop of the `RadioListTile` add this code:

```
onChanged: (value) => evaluate ? null : value = 0,
```

hope this was helpful!