# How can I disable a Radio button using a short hand IF in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a `Radio` and I want to disable it with a condition, like:

```
if (enabled == true){
*enable radio button*
} else {
*disable radio button*
}
```

EDIT

I'll add the complete code of my class because I only added a portion of it.

Here is the complete code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class RadioButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String label;
  final int groupValue;
  final int value;
  final ValueChanged<int> onChanged;

  const RadioButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.label,
      required this.groupValue,
      required this.value,
      required this.onChanged});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Radio<int>(
                        groupValue: groupValue,
                        value: value,
                        onChanged: (int? newValue) {
                          onChanged(newValue!);
                        }),
                  ),
                  Text(label),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [Check this I think this will work for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65559906/14216705)

Comment: I tried your approach and have this error "The argument type 'void Function(int)?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(int)'". Also I edited my code so you can see the complete class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To disable a `Radio` button, set `onChanged` to `null`:

```
return Radio(
      value: 1,
      groupValue: 1,
      onChanged: null,
    );
```

**Edit**: To disable it based on a condition:

```dart
var isDisabled = true;
    Radio(
      value: 1,
      groupValue: 1,
      onChanged: isDisabled ? null : (value) {},
```

---

From the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio/onChanged.html) on `onChanged`:

> If null, the radio button will be displayed as disabled.

---

You can keep this trick of setting `null` in mind as it also disables other `Icons`/widgets.

Comment: I've edited my question because I wasn't clear about it, my bad, i want to disable it using a condition on it, how can I do it?

Comment: @EderSavillon I've edited my answer. Check if that helps.